# Does InstallShield Limited Edition LE support 32 bit & 64 bit deployments?

Tags: installshield, installshield-le

I've installed InstallShield LE for Visual Studio 2012 and created an msi. It works fine installing on a 64 bit machine, but on a 32 bit machine I get an error "(null) is not a valid Win32 application".

My project is built to support Any CPU as the platform target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your machine is 64 bit, it will only make the 64 bit .msi file when you build "Any CPU".  I had the same issue and found the best solution is just to use a 32 bit platform or make two separate projects and have two different installers. If you want to have both 32 bit and 64 bit .msi files in a single setup project you have to get the Pro version.

The answer to this question discuses how to do this.
[Installshield 2012 : Identify 32 or 64 bit Operating system and install appropriate ActiveX control - Basic msi installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434840/installshield-2012-identify-32-or-64-bit-operating-system-and-install-appropri)

Comment: Thanks. That makes life a bit awkward - I'll have to get hold of a 32bit machine! Grr.

Comment: FYI -- This doesn't seem to be entirely true.  I am having the opposite problem.  I am attempting to build the 64 bit installer on a 64 bit machine and all I can get is the 32 bit version.

Comment: This is because your assemblies are not compiled in 64 bits, this is how installshield works, if there is no 64 binary, registry or configuration, installshield will crate a 32 bit setup version

Comment: Is there any way to tell which component is 64-bit?