# InstallShield adding diffrerent prerequisite for x86 and x64

Tags: installshield

I want to add different version of Crystal Reports as a setup prerequisite using InstallShield depending on platform. For x86 32bit version should be installed, for x64 - 64bit. 
What kind of condition should I add to do so? I've found that I can select particular OS as condition but there is no option to just select 32 or 64 bit.
Thanks in advance.

UPD1: In InstallShield I can choose the following types of condition:

1. Check if registry entry exists. I wanted to check for WoW6332Node
   but then I found that this node can be listed in 32bit OS:
   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2582176 Also I found that I can
   check some registry entries
   https://superuser.com/questions/290906/check-if-32-or-64-bit-windows-os-via-registry/290929
   but I'm not sure that they present in all windows versions.
2. Check if certain file exists. I can check some file in Program Files
   (x86) folder to detect 64bit OS, but it's not a good idea in my
   opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the VersionNT64 property for this.
More details can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372497(v=vs.85).aspx

Edit: As it can be seen in the documentation, this property is only set on a 64-bit computer otherwise it is empty.

EDIT: 13.VIII.2014
After the prerequisite has been selected to be added to your installation package, a feature has been assigned.
So, you can go in the "Features" view and select the created feature. I can see it has a Condition field, most likely there you can use the VersionNT64 property.

Comment: Thank you! But how to use this property in prerequisite condition?
I use InstallShield 2012 and the only types of conditions are:
1) A registry key/entry - check if exists or has a specified value
2) Check that file exists or not
3) Setup is running on a specified platform - I can choose OS, but I have to select all 64bit operating systems and it's not convenient.

Comment: In my feature view there is only one main feature.